# InDesign Script - Table footer and insertion point

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

I developed a script for inDesign, which loop inDesign files 1 by 1, page by page, scans text frames, find specific codes inside the text and for each code it checks if the code is inside a list, if yes, the script will insert a small image after the code, if not the script pass to next text frame.

Because example is better that big talk, here is an example:

[image]

After code it has this small black/grey image inserted. That perfectly work for every code, except for codes on last table row.

I have check several points before ask for help:
-Script detect the code correctly (I even can edit the text with the script to make sure).
-The table cell has enough space to insert the image (I also trie to give a higher height to the row).
-I tried to resize the image, make it smaller.
-The script correctly add the image if I add an empty row after the last one... so it's really a last row problem...

Now here is the part of the script that fail

```
        app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = currentREF;
        var myFoundItems = app.activeDocument.findText();

        for ( var bh = 0; bh < myFoundItems.length; bh++ ) {


        myLastIns = myFoundItems[bh].insertionPoints.length;
        myInsPointOk = myFoundItems[bh].insertionPoints[myLastIns - 1];

        if ( bh == 0 ) {
            myTf = myInsPointOk.parentTextFrames[0];
        }

        try {
            //Insert/place the logo
            var myImgPath = logoImage;
            var myBlockImg = myInsPointOk.rectangles.add( {strokeWeight: 0, strokeColor: "None", fillColor: "None", geometricBounds: [ 0, 0, 1, 1 ]} );
            myBlockImg.contentType = ContentType.graphicType;
            myBlockImg.anchoredObjectSettings.anchoredPosition = AnchorPosition.INLINE_POSITION;
            myBlockImg.anchoredObjectSettings.anchorXoffset = 0;
            myBlockImg.anchoredObjectSettings.anchorYoffset = 0;
            myBlockImg.place( File( myImgPath ) );
            myBlockImg.fit( FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT );
        } catch ( e ) {

            //Warning, the code has been find but the script didn't success to insert it
            $.writeln( "La référence " + normalFormatRef + " à été trouvée dans le fichier " + app.activeDocument.name + " mais le script n'à pas réussit à insérer le picto." );
            arrError.push( "La référence " + normalFormatRef + " à été trouvée dans le fichier " + app.activeDocument.name + " mais le script n'à pas réussit à insérer le picto." );

        }
        }
```

What I guess is the script doesn't find the insertion point inside last row's table... but why?
Or maybe I don't guess correctly...

At the end, the script stop on the line each time it try to add an image on the last row...

```
       var myBlockImg = myInsPointOk.rectangles.add( {strokeWeight: 0, strokeColor: "None", fillColor: "None", geometricBounds: [ 0, 0, 1, 1 ]} );
```

That's why I'm guessing it's the insertion point that fail.

Comment: Does it work if you use `..findText(true)`, to get the list of found items in reversed order? If so, I can explain why :)

Comment: Thanx but it didn't works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly thanx for your answers!
Then I finally found the solution, I post below:

```js
if ( myFoundItems[bh].parent.constructor.name == "Cell" ) {
         //Only for text include in cells, temporary increase the height of the parent's row
         var previousRowHeight = myFoundItems[bh].parent.minimumHeight;
         myFoundItems[bh].parent.minimumHeight = "15mm";
         myFoundItems[bh].parent.parent.parent.fit( FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT );
}

         var myBlockImg = myFoundItems[bh].parent.insertionPoints[-1].rectangles.add( {strokeWeight: 0,  strokeColor: "None", fillColor: "None", geometricBounds: [ 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1 ]} );
         myBlockImg.contentType = ContentType.graphicType;
         myBlockImg.anchoredObjectSettings.anchoredPosition = AnchorPosition.INLINE_POSITION;
         myBlockImg.anchoredObjectSettings.anchorXoffset = 0;
         myBlockImg.anchoredObjectSettings.anchorYoffset = 0;
         myBlockImg.place( File( myImgPath ) );
         myBlockImg.fit( FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT );

if ( myFoundItems[bh].parent.constructor.name == "Cell" ) {
        //Only for text include in cells, reset the height of the parent's row
        myFoundItems[bh].parent.minimumHeight = previousRowHeight;
        myFoundItems[bh].parent.parent.parent.fit( FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT );
}
```

To explain a while, what I found out was increase the row's height was not enough, it also needed to fit the parent's text block.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing obvious. Let me propose this approach. I generally choose object styles rather than editing object properties within the script. That lets the user possibly easily edit the object appearance and location after the script ran. It also avoid the fit call.

```js
var main = function(){
 var doc, fgp, cgp, found = [], n = 0, text, parent, rect, os,
 osProps = {
   name:"picto",
 },
 picto = File ( Folder.desktop+"/picto.ai"), 
 uip = app.scriptPreferences.properties;
 
 if ( !app.properties.activeDocument) return;
 
 if ( !picto.exists ) {
  alert("The picto file could't be found!" );
  return;
 }

 doc = app.activeDocument;
 fgp = app.findGrepPreferences.properties;
 cgp = app.changeGrepPreferences.properties;
 
 app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = null;
 
 app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "(\\d{2}\\.){4}\\d{2}";
 
 found = doc.findGrep();
 n = found.length;
 
 if ( !n ) return;
 
 app.scriptPreferences.enableRedraw = false;
 app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.NEVER_INTERACT;
 
 os = doc.objectStyles.item ("picto");
 !os.isValid && os = doc.objectStyles.add(osProps);
 
 while ( n-- ) {
  text = found[n];
  parent = text.parent;
  if ( parent instanceof Cell 
  && parent.parentRow.cells[-1]==parent ) {
   rect = text.insertionPoints[-1].rectangles.add({geometricBounds: [ 0, 0, 1, 1 ]});
   rect.appliedObjectStyle = os;
   rect.place ( picto );
  }
 }
 
 app.findGrepPreferences.properties = fgp;
 app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = cgp;
 app.scriptPreferences.properties = uip;
}

var u;
app.doScript ( main, u, u, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "Add picto" );
```

Also I picked Grep over text for text search as it may avoid a loop through the ref. However It might not be a good match if the refs have variable patterns.

[image: The result…]